# Scrollview Autolayout with Tabbar and Navigationbar

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uinavigationbar, tabbar

I need to set constraints in uiscrollview in viewcontroller containing navigationbar and tabbar.I have placed a uiview(contentView) inside scrollview which is of same height as of scrollview.These are the things which I have set curently,

1. set 4 constraints for scrollview(top,bottom,left,right) with
   constraints to margin unchecked which is 0 for all edges.
2. set 4 constraints for uiview(contentView) inside
   scrollview(top,bottom,left,right) with constraints to margin
   unchecked which is 0 for all edges.
3. set equal width and equal height
   for scrollview and UIView(contentView)

output is displaying like this uiview(contentView) gets placed lower about 64 px (approx).This view should not place like this.Can anyone help me to solve this.

Here is the project demo which I have worked and [can be downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqonpjldkqgvvxc/demoScrollviewAutolayout.zip?dl=0)

Comment: You should read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html Particularly **Adding a Navigation Controller to a Tab Bar Interface** *An app that uses a tab bar controller can also use navigation controllers in one or more tabs. When combining these two types of view controller in the same user interface, the tab bar controller always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers.*

Answer (score 2):

You might try `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None not working and I have pinned the scrolview to top of viewcontroller's view

Comment: You might try `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false ,its not working

Comment: You should show more about the overall structure of your project. Do you disagree with my premise that the scroll view is adjusting the content inset to match the height of the navigation bar?

Comment: yes initially I logged the scrollview offset its the offset y is -64 px .(i.e) Its printing as (0,-64) not sure why

Comment: Right, the status bar is 20 points high and the standard navigation bar in iOS is 44 points high 20 + 44 = 64. The view controller is setting the inset to accommodate scrollviews extending under a translucent navigation bar. The standard way of turning this off is setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` or `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None` or unchecking "Adjust scroll view insets" in the inspector of a UIViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Select the scene and in the attributes inspector, uncheck: "Under Top Bars" and "Under Bottom Bars".

[image]

Then in the storyboard make the scroll view start at the very top of the View Controller, where the navigation bar starts, and then the UIView, where the navigation Bar ends.

Later, select the Scroll View and set the constraints as they come by default.

[image]

I guess it's not the cleanest way to do it but I had the same issue and worked for me.

Comment: will try and let you know. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: How was it? Could you fix the problem?

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue ,I hve uploaded the project can pls have a look at it

Comment: I worked on your project and the scrollview doesn't start at the top of the VC, it starts at the end of the navBar. Only the smaller view should start there. Also, you don't even have a class for that VC, you have to add it and set from the view did load the scrollview height that you want. To be honest, i recommend you to start a new tutorial from scratch because there a few things missing in your project and will be quicker. Take care ;)

Comment: Actually I created that for showing wat was the issue here .It was a demo project and one more thing I have kept the scrollview at the top of VC but the same issue exists. You can try in that

Comment: These are the steps I followed:
1. Delete all constraints,
2. Set VC size to 4 inch and made it larger,
3. Bring ScrollView to the top and adjust it to 4inch size, and UIView after NavBar,
4. Added constraint to both them. 

Here is the working project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iwatkkoazcecl27/AABzCOjP8e8DLRIY_w8mCLeUa?dl=0

Comment: Thank you very much for your time will check this out.

Comment: This wat your output look like: [URL](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzjbtu87uqrs6ab/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Mar%2022%2C%202016%2C%209.58.46%20PM.png?dl=0)

Comment: Sure, because I don't know how you want it to look like. But you can change the constraints there. If you see thought, now the scrolling works and everything starts where it has to. That was your problem no? that it was starting 64px below...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107059/discussion-between-super-xtreem-and-victor-rius).

Comment: If your problem was fixed, (It was in the project I sent you) I would really appreciate your vote up for all the time spent on this. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

The Tab Bar has to be set in the tree UNDER the scrollView, like this:

[image: controller tree]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge()
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution for it,The parent ViewController class is set to under top bar and disabling it and changed the frame accordingly in the parent and set the same property and frame to child viewcontroller fixed the issue.